# How to specify connection to data source for LDAPs context source?

Tags: java, spring, ldap, datasource

I'm using Spring mvc with LDAP authentication against active directory. What I have now works but my contextSource  properties: url, managerDN, and managerPassword are hard coded. I'd like to move these properties into my server.xml as a resource and use a datasource to specify these connection settings. My thought is that the managerDN can be used like a user name and then the rest will work. The only issue is that contextSource doesn't have any methods for this. contextSource is an object created from contextSourceBuilder. Anyone have any ideas as to how to do this?

```
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
                .userSearchBase("OU=Accounts")
                .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
                .groupSearchBase("OU=Groups")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://myurl:portNum")
                    .managerDn("stuff")
                    .managerPassword("things");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set it in *.properties file, let Spring load it and then use:

```
@Value(${ldap.manager})
String managerDn;
@Value(${ldap.manager.password})
String managerPassword;
[...]
.managerDn(managerDn)
     .managerPassword(managerPassword);
```

Or:
Use org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource
 set user/passoword in the setters and set it in

```
.contextSource(youFancySpringContext);
```